# What does Scientific Managing Editor at Elsevier do? What are their responsibilities?

Tags: job, editors, elsevier

I am planning to apply for a position at Elsevier. They are looking for Scientific Managing Editor. I have no idea what to expect in such a job profile? I am a PhD with a year of postdoc experience.

Is there anyone who have worked in this capacity or have applied for similar positions before?

Comment: What does their job advertisement say?

Comment: @allure Key responsibilities will include:
- Establishing relationships with diverse editorial teams

- Assessing submitted research papers and reviewer feedback
- Guiding authors through various aspects of the publishing process

- Supporting authors' publishing decisions related to transfer between journals
- Working collaboratively with academic board members and in-house editors
- Building effective working relationships with colleagues across Cell Press and beyond

Comment: Probably edit that into the question, and see these questions as possible duplicates: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/137410/what-should-one-consider-when-pondering-a-career-as-a-scientific-editor and https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46402/career-options-in-scientific-academic-publishing-for-phds-and-postdocs

Comment: I suggest to call them and ask.