# What's the career progression of associate scientific editor at a major publishing house?

Tags: career-path, editors, publishers, non-academic-staff

As someone who has been offered a position with Springer Nature as an associate scientific editor, I am unclear about the career progression in such an industry?

I am currently a 2 year postdoc in chemical engineering in the US.

Is it possible to shift to an industry other than publishing after reaching a senior position or if this doesn't work out after a year or two?

How about returning to a research position (tenure track) or research associate position after one or two years?

Comment: Isn't this already answered in [Career options in scientific/academic publishing for PhDs and Postdocs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46402/career-options-in-scientific-academic-publishing-for-phds-and-postdocs)? This was linked for the previous question you asked, as well.

Comment: @Allure The links and the career progression you mentioned in your comment were about someone who doesn't have a technical background and a PhD. Their career progression would likely be very different than a person with a PhD and/or postdoc. Since this is an academic community, there might be some graduated PhD student who traversed through this path or might know someone who has.

Comment: If that's the focus of your question then it's a duplicate of [What should one consider when pondering a career as a scientific editor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/137410/what-should-one-consider-when-pondering-a-career-as-a-scientific-editor) which explicitly deals with having a PhD in academic publishing. Voting ot close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should one consider when pondering a career as a scientific editor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/137410/what-should-one-consider-when-pondering-a-career-as-a-scientific-editor)

Answer (score 7):

In math, in the U.S., if you did not already have tenure, this might be a bad thing. That is, although it might be a useful activity, it's not directly about research or teaching, and somewhat indicates less interest in those aspects of academe.

After tenure, taking a year or two leave to do such things, or to work at the National Science Foundation, is considered legitimate service... but it's not a strong point toward tenure, at least in my observation. You'd want/need to continue research output during your time there, which might be difficult due to commitments of time and energy, even apart from Chem E lab needs...

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change industry afterwards. Even as a technical person, although the more you are in publishing, the less likely it will be.